# How to select a timestamp from MySQL without rows

Tags: php, mysqli

Recently, I've been working on a perks system for donors or supporters of my servers however, I've ran into a little issue to where I can't exactly select the data that I want from MySQL which returned an integer

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), `expiration`)  
FROM `unclaimed` WHERE `steamid`="STEAM_0:1:56987503"
```

**(Returns as 525530)**

However, I can't really select this data as it is not in any row and just returns as a result.
[image: phpmyadmin snapshot]

I've also tried multiple variations of PHP code to get the result instead of the row but those caused errors, so then I tried this final variation and it gave me a blank page:
[image: script snapshot]

What I hope to accomplish is a simple script to check if the number is negative or not, and if it is to change rank to 0

Comment: Screenshots are not viable question code. Also, that data **is** in a row as the first and only column. If you wanted to give it a more usable name (which you don't have to because you can just use the column index), you would *alias* it, ie `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(...) AS tdiff ...`

Comment: Also, **never** say something caused errors without explicitly copying and pasting the error into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the *mysqli* extension gives meaningful errors by putting this before creating your connection.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Then, you should be using prepared statements with bound parameters if there's user input involved.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('
    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), `expiration`)
    FROM `unclaimed` WHERE `steamid` = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $SteamID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($diff);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($diff <= 0) {
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your row can be returned with:

`$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Then you can echo it.  Also assign the timestamp to an alias in your query so that you can easily access it.

Edit: Change your query to this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), `expiration`)  steamTimestamp
FROM `unclaimed` WHERE `steamid`="STEAM_0:1:56987503"
```

and then you can reference it with $row['steamTimestamp'];

Comment: The default fetch type for `mysqli_result::fetch_array` is `MYSQLI_BOTH` so it would still have indexed columns

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after, was more focused on the images.

Comment: Also, OP is using *mysqli* and it's called an *alias*, not *"assign the timestamp to a variable"*

Comment: I have to agree with @Phil This is misleading for future readers and should be corrected. This `$var` is a variable .